# How to put Textview value into URL to receive from PHP using $_GET

Tags: java, php

Forgive me for asking this, But im new in android development. So I'm trying to put the `TextView` value into my URL, that in my webservice(PHP) I have $_GET to test my query and show only the desired match value of field name "WHERE CODE_ID = .$sample."

CameraTestActivity.class

```
if (!scanText.getText().toString().matches("")){

    //set the scan text from bar code label
    scanText.setText(sym.getData());

     //if Text scan the Content Automatic go to another Activity and pass the scan text from Main Activity

    Intent i = new Intent(CameraTestActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    i.putExtra("code_id", content);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

MainActivity2.class

```
//trying to put the TextValue of scanText into tvView
tvView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
tvView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("code_id"));

String ServerURL = ("https://asec-domain.000webhostapp.com/select.php?code_id="  + tvView);
```

getAll.php

```
if (isset($_GET['code_id'])) 
{ 
  $id  = $_GET['code_id'];
}  

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($HOST='localhost', $USER='id4400742_asec_domain', $PASS='asec@l0cal', $DB='id4400742_tbl_data');

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ComputerDetails WHERE CODE_ID= id "; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {

 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }

 echo $json;

 }

 else 
 {

 echo "No Results Found.";
 }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this

If id is a number:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ComputerDetails WHERE CODE_ID = ".$id;
```

If id is a String

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ComputerDetails WHERE CODE_ID = '".$id."'";
```

Otherwise id is just the String "id" and not a number you retrieve from GET.
And by the way this is not a good practice because of SQL Injection

And always hide your passwords and usernames when you post something

So in Android you are missing this:

```
//trying to put the TextValue of scanText into tvView
tvView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
tvView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("code_id"));

//You are not getting the string you are just passing the textview
String result = getIntent().getExtras().getString("code_id");

String ServerURL = ("https://asec-domain.000webhostapp.com/select.php?code_id="  + result);
```

Comment: yes sir i did it already..but the result give me "No Result Found". Im curious if my 'code_id' in my php really getting the data from TextView in Android

Comment: In Android you have to make a request to the server. Where is your request ?

Comment: Undefined variable: id in /storage/ssd2/742/4400742/public_html/select.php on line 21
Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/ssd2/742/4400742/public_html/select.php on line 25
No Results Found.

Comment: I change the query you say but it gives me an error

Comment: You have to define $id, above the if statement like this:

`$id;

if (isset($_GET['code_id'])) 
{ 
  $id  = $_GET['code_id'];
}`

Otherwise you cannot access $id because it is a local variable

Comment: When i Try to encode manually https://asec-domain.000webhostapp.com/select.php?code_id=8000000001 output is this:[{"ID":"1","CODE_ID":"8000000001","PERI_TYPE":"CPU","OWNER":"JOUIE CEPRES","DEPARTMENT":"IT","PERI_MODEL":"ALIENWARE","SERIAL_NUMBER":"51232123213","REMARKS":"GOOD"}]

Comment: I fixed the error by adding $id=0 in the top of if (isset($_GET['code_id'])) 
{ 
  $id  = $_GET['code_id'];
}

Comment: does it mean the Im wrong in Android ? because when i try to manually encode in my browser it give me this:  asec-domain.000webhostapp.com/select.php?code_id=8000000001 output is this:[{"ID":"1","CODE_ID":"8000000001","PERI_TYPE":"CPU","OW‌​NER":"JOUIE CEPRES","DEPARTMENT":"IT","PERI_MODEL":"ALIENWARE","SERIAL_N‌​UMBER":"51232123213"‌​,"REMARKS":"GOOD"}]